# Is it possible to read/write software reviews in different languages?

Tags: 11.04, software-center, reviews

Does anyone know if it possible to write/display a review in a different language than your own primary one in the Software Center?

Answer (score 2):

You can logout, choose your own user again, but on the bottom of the screen set another language to use, it will change the prefered language when the Software Center look for revisions, but you may notice that the whole system will use that dictionary and to get back to your default language you will need to logout again and change that language.

Summarising, it's still a lacking feature and logging out and in isn't the most convenient way to read revisions in other languages. Hope they'll include this feature in Oneiric's Software Center!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can launch it from a terminal with

```
LC_ALL=lang software-center
```

That way, everything should be set to a different locale.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to write review in other language as long as you can type them. Software Center can also display reviews in other languages, at least I saw come Chinese reviews in some software infos.

[image: Reviews in Chinese]

But until now, you cannot choose to "only" view reviews written by a certain language.

Comment: Maybe editing your [preferred languages](https://translations.launchpad.net/+editmylanguages) in your Launchpad account?

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not possible from inside software-center. The only way right now is to create a seperate user and pick the language you want at the GDM-Login.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to system settings?keyboard>layouts, you can add another language keyboard layout. An icon will appear in the panel which you can use to change layouts. If you change the layout when you are ready to type the review that language will be used for what you write. This is what happens when I change the layout to Greek when writing this answer:

αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω

You will continue typing in that language until you change back to GBr (English)

Regards.