# Ubuntu Software Center reviews in own language

Tags: software-center

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software center: review in a different language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45826/software-center-review-in-a-different-language)

Can I only see the reviews written in my language?

This is immensely annoying, not a lot of Dutch speaking people write reviews. And when they do, they write it in English anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/45826/2079

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that might not be possible for now. For me, most reviews I see was written in English, sometimes I wanted the reviews in my language as well, but I can't. This may be a good function to recommend to the developers.